# How to dynamically change Bootstrap Password Strength tooltip color based on Password Score

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've included Bootstrap's password "strength-meter" plugin on my registration page, and it works fine. However, I would like to expand on this and shift the color for each respective message (similar to the success, warning, and danger alert colors). Currently, I've edited the CSS to Red only. I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to change the CSS element dynamically?

Here is the section of HTML on the page starting from the container div directly below the body to the end of the container div:

```
<div class="container">

<?php if (isset($successMessage)) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success text-center" role="alert"><strong>Success! </strong><?php echo $successMessage; ?> </div><?php } ?>
<?php if (isset($redirectMessage)) { ?>
    <div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="Redirecting" style="width:100%"><?php echo $redirectMessage; ?> </div></div><?php } ?>
<?php if (isset($failMessage)) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade in text-center" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><strong>Error: </strong> <?php echo $failMessage; ?>
    </div><?php } ?>
<div class="password-fail"></div>
<form id="registration-form" class="form-signin" method="POST">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Register Account</h2>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
    </div>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required autofocus>
    <div class="col-lg-16" id="tooltip-viewport"> <!--containing viewport for tooltip -->
    <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
    <input type="password" name="password2" id="verifyPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm" required>
    <div class="button-container">
        <button id="register-button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block disabled" type="submit">Register</button>
        <div class="login-page-link-container">
            <a href="src/login.php" class="login-page-link">I'm already a member!</a>
        </div>
</form>
</div>
```

[image: Snapshot to show Registration Form]

Here is the styling for it in my forms.css file:

```
/*
TOOLTIP FOR PASSWORD STRENGTH
*/
.tooltip {
font-size: 16px;
}
.tooltip-inner {
background-color: red;
color: white;
}
```

And finally, here is the Javascript function I wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#inputPassword').strengthMeter('tooltip', { //#inputPassword is input id
        hierarchy: { //tooltip hierarchy

            '0': 'Your Password is Empty',
            '1': 'You\'re kidding right?',
            '10': 'Very Weak',
            '20': 'Kinda Weak',
            '30': 'Good',
            '40': 'Strong',
            '50': 'Very Strong'
        },
        tooltip: {
            viewport: '#tooltip-viewport'} //containing div for password input
    });
});
```

If it's not possible, I'm fine with that. I've tried to search through the plugin I downloaded, and searching via Google and S.O. didn't give me anything in relation to how my code is set up.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no built in options or callbacks in the Bootstrap Strength Meter, so it's not possible without modifying the underlying library (specifically, tooltip.js would need to be extended in order to add this functionality)

Source: http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-strength-meter/

Comment: I guess technically I can accept this as the answer. I'm not skilled enough yet to edit the code, so it will have to remain one color for now. If I knew how to call the score values (10, 20, etc) and do an if/else block with something like if(score is 20) { $('tooltip-inner').css('background-color', 'green') } that would be great. I'll put that aside for now and work on the rest of my site. Thanks for the tip (no pun intended).